Retrieve all array elements if child array contains a certain element in JSON/RediSearch
I am using Redis with RedisJSON module and RediSearch, and I have some entries such as those below.
JSON.SET uuid_1 $ '{ "type": "game1", "players": ["player1", "player2"] }'
JSON.SET uuid_2 $ '{ "type": "game1", "players": ["player3", "player2"] }'

What I want to achieve is some sort of query that returns both the uuids and the whole array, when such array contains some target elements.
For example, when I query:

player1 -> [uuid_1, ["players", ["player1", "player2"] ]
player2 -> [uuid_2, ["players", ["player3", "player2"] ].

I have also checked out this answer, but I cannot fully reproduce it in my case.
What I was able to get is first to create the index:
 FT.CREATE idx ON JSON SCHEMA '$.players[*]' AS players TAG $.type AS gameType TEXT

and then either retrieve only the uuids:
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player2} NOCONTENT
1) (integer) 2
2) "uuid_1"
3) "uuid_2"

or the whole key
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player2}
1) (integer) 2
2) "uuid_1"
3) 1) "$"
   2) "{\"type\":\"game1\",\"players\":[\"player1\",\"player2\"]}"
4) "uuid_2"
5) 1) "$"
   2) "{\"type\":\"game1\",\"players\":[\"player3\",\"player2\"]}"

Unfortunately, if I want to retrieve only the player attribute, it seems that is incomplete and it returns me only the first element:
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player2} RETURN 1 players
1) (integer) 2
2) "uuid_1"
3) 1) "players"
   2) "player1"
4) "uuid_2"
5) 1) "players"
   2) "player"

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player1} RETURN 1 players
1) (integer) 1
2) "uuid_1"
3) 1) "players"
   2) "player1"


This is a bug in early dialects of Search that wasn't corrected in the spirit of preserving backward compatibility. You need to tell Search to use at least DIALECT 3 to get the entire array back.
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player2} RETURN 1 players DIALECT 3
1) (integer) 2
2) "uuid_1"
3) 1) "players"
   2) "[\"player1\",\"player2\"]"
4) "uuid_2"
5) 1) "players"
   2) "[\"player3\",\"player2\"]"

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx @players:{player1} RETURN 1 players DIALECT 3
1) (integer) 1
2) "uuid_1"
3) 1) "players"
   2) "[\"player1\",\"player2\"]"

You can set the default dialect when you start Redis or by setting a configuration option in  when Redis is running:
$ redis-server --loadmodule ./redisearch.so DEFAULT_DIALECT 3

FT.CONFIG SET DEFAULT_DIALECT 3

Also, there's a handy dandy web page with all the basic dialect info you might care to know.

I was not aware. Just one more clarification: is the dialect incremental isn't it? So if I have a bare new app, it might be pointful to state DEFAULT DIALECT 5, which is the latest one, since there can be no issue with retro compatibility.

For major version 2, yes this can be useful. No dialect version will be dropped. Just notice that when a new dialect gets out, it means some queries will be parsed differently or return different reply structure. When you change a dialect version you should verify you get the results you expect
